# How to automatically correlate a time series with other ones?

Tags: matlab

I tried searching google for this, but could not find anything even remotely related to what I want.

I have several time series representing parameters over time.
I have a parameter named "error", and since I do not know where does this error come from, I would like matlab to help me find the origin of the error.
The idea would be to correlate automatically the time series with all others available in order to try and see if the error is due to one or another parameter.

(When I google matlab autocorrelation, I found answers about how to know if a time series is correlated with itself, which is absolutely not my concern)

The ideal output would be a model of my error.
If it could use, if needed, simple transformations of the other parameters available, it would be perfect.
For instance, the error could be the sum of parameter A * K1 + K2 * parameter B's derivative + K3 * lagged parameter C

Is there anything like this available in matlab ?

Thank you

Comment: Just FYI the term "auto" in autocorrelation doesn't mean automatic, it derives from the greek prefix "auto" which means "self" (i.e. correlation with itself). What you are interested in is cross-correlation which can be performed using [`xcorr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [corrcoef](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html)

Example:

```
a = rand(1000,1);
b = rand(1000,1);
c = rand(1000,1);
d = rand(1000,1);
error = a.*0.75 + c.*0.25;  %Sim an error that is caused by both a & c.
corrcoef([error,a,b,c,d])
ans =
    1.0000    0.9483    0.0399    0.3077    0.0449
    0.9483    1.0000    0.0301   -0.0102    0.0245
    0.0399    0.0301    1.0000    0.0354   -0.0312
    0.3077   -0.0102    0.0354    1.0000    0.0681
    0.0449    0.0245   -0.0312    0.0681    1.0000
```

From the output you can see that `error` is positively correlated with `a` and `c` since the correlation coefficients are positive and relatively large at positions (1,2) & (1,4).  The diagonals are all 1.0 which indicated each element correlates with itself but you can just ignore those.